# Is there a direct way to deeply nest in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In other words: can JavaScript automatically create object parents?

In an example where "testObject" is already created...

```
let testObject = {}
```

...this throws an error...

```
testObject.parent.child.grandchild = { foo: 'ya' };
```

This works but is a lot of code...

```
  testObject.parent = {};
  testObject.parent.child = {};
  testObject.parent.child.grandchild = { foo: 'ya' };
```

Things get more complicated if the middle generation might have data, so checks are needed...

```
  if (!testObject.parent) {
    testObject.parent = {};
  }
  if (!testObject.parent.child) {
    testObject.parent.child = {};
  }
  testObject.parent.child.grandchild = { foo: 'ya' };
```

What I'm looking for is a direct way to create middle generations in an object if they're not already created.  Is this possible with less coding than these examples? (Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate question!)

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set

Comment: you call them generations but those are actually properties of objects.. and if you try access to properties of a an `undefined` value the error thrown is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`. The point being that if you use a property name not defined in an object, its value will be `undefined` indeed and you cannot have success when you attempt to access its own properties further. You may be interested to [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`??=` operator:

```js
const testObject = {};

((testObject.parent ??= {}).child ??= {}).grandchild = {foo: 'ya'};

console.log(testObject);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander, that's an elegant solution!

Comment: For future readers: Alexander's suggestion to use the ??= (nullish coalescing assignment) operator seems to be working well for me.  Further reference can be found here...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment